# jhipster injection on servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jhipster

I created a servlet, but I'm not able to do the injection of a repository object. Has anyone had this problem?

my config in WebConfigurer:

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    log.info("Web application configuration, using profiles: {}", Arrays.toString(env.getActiveProfiles()));
    // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherServlet = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    dispatcherServlet.register(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class);

    // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherServlet));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");
```

my servlet:

```
 @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/servlet/preview")
    public class ServletPreViewHtml extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Autowired
        private PagecontentRepository pagecontentRepository;

        public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
            doGet(request,response);
        }
        public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            Pagecontent p = pagecontentRepository.getOne(2l); //line 34
            out.println(p.getFullHtml());
```

always returns me the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null  at
>   br.com.dmsolutions.netfarmacontentmanager.web.rest.ServletPreViewHtml.doGet(ServletPreViewHtml.java:34)

line of NPE: `pagecontentRepository.getOne(2L);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Gaël Marziou, but you can also use `@ServletComponentScan`, part of Spring Boot 1.3.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.3-Release-Notes#support-for-webservlet-webfilter-and-weblistener

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `@WebServlet`, I would rather use `@Controller` so that Spring can inject your repository.